# I need a validator for my input form for website URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to create an HTML input form field to check if users input text in this format `www.domain.com`. I will like a validator that will check if the user input in that format it can end in `.ae,.net.org and soon` but it must start with `www.` and end with `.com, .org, .net etc` just want to make sure the user add text after the dot. Basically I want a prefix can't be edited and the input of user should end with .ae,.com,.net etc

Comment: Regex Is the answer

Comment: You are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url).